# Unknown issue for a Monty Hall problem Java program

Tags: java

At the end of the program, when it prints out what was behind your door, it gets the default string instead of the mutated one, but the mutated one was called and worked perfectly fine with the previous method. Why?

Also, the answer to what is behind your chosen door always seems to be the bad prize (goat). Is This just a coincidence?

If you spot any other errors in my program please comment below.

**This is class 1**

```java
package montehallproblem;

import java.util.Random;

public class GameInfo {
    private boolean reset;

    private String D1;
    private String D2;
    private String D3;

    private String res1;
    private String res2;

    private int choice;

    public GameInfo(){
        res1 ="new car";
        res2 ="goat";
        choice = 404;
        reset = false;

        // NOTE: If un-mutated, the Door Strings will default to this result every time
        D1 = res1;
        D2 = res2;
        D3 = res2;
    }

    public void manualSetChoicesAndDoors(String one, String two, int d1, int d2, int d3){
        setResult1(one);
        setResult2(two);

        //NOTE: This allows the OLC to utilize the previously typed prize strings;
        if(d1==1){
            setDoor1(res1);
        }else if(d1==2){
            setDoor1(res2);
        }else  if(d2==1){
            setDoor2(res1);
        }else if(d2==2){
            setDoor2(res2);
        }else  if(d3==1){
            setDoor3(res1);
        }else if(d3==2){
            setDoor3(res2);
        }
    }

    public void setDoor1(String x){
        D1 = x;
    }

    public void setDoor2(String x){
        D2 = x;
    }

    public void setDoor3(String x){
        D3 = x;
    }

    public void setResult1(String x){
        res1 = x;
    }

    public void setResult2(String x){
        res2 = x;
    }

    public void setChoice(int x){
        choice = x;
    }

    public void setReset(boolean x){
        reset = x;
    }

    public String getDoor1(){
        return D1;
    }

    public String getDoor2(){
        return D2;
    }

    public String getDoor3(){
        return D3;
    }

    public String getResult1(){
        return res1;
    }

    public String getResult2(){
        return res2;
    }

    public int getChoice(){
        return choice;
    }

    public void generatePrizeDoor(){
        if(reset){
            Random rand = new Random();
            int prize = rand.nextInt(3);

            //NOTE: this determines which door has the best prize behind it (res1)
            switch(prize){
            case 1:
                setDoor1(getResult1());
                setDoor2(getResult2());
                setDoor3(getResult2());
                break;
            case 2:
                setDoor1(getResult2());
                setDoor2(getResult1());
                setDoor1(getResult2());
                break;
            case 3:
                setDoor1(getResult2());
                setDoor1(getResult2());
                setDoor1(getResult1());
                System.out.println("a new game generates...");
            }
        }
    }

    public void revealBadDoor(){

        //NOTE: This reveals one of the doors with the bad prize in it;
        //NOTE: Appends "used" to door string so that it can be detected later
        if(getDoor1().contains(getResult2()) && getChoice() != 1){
            System.out.println("Monty reveals door one contains a "+getResult2());
            setDoor1(getDoor1()+"used");
        }else if(getDoor2().contains(getResult2()) && getChoice() != 2){
            System.out.println("Monty reveals door two contains a "+getResult2());
            setDoor2(getDoor2()+"used");
        }else if(getDoor3().contains(getResult2()) && getChoice() != 3){
            System.out.println("Monty reveals door one contains a "+getResult2());
            setDoor3(getDoor3()+"used");
        }
    }

    public void switchDoorChoice(String x){

        //NOTE: This changes your door choice to the door string that doesnt contain "used"
        if(x.contains("yes")){
            switch(getChoice()){
            case 1:
                if(getDoor2().contains("used")){
                    setChoice(3);
                }else if(getDoor3().contains("used")){
                    setChoice(2);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if(getDoor3().contains("used")){
                    setChoice(1);
                }else if(getDoor1().contains("used")){
                    setChoice(3);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(getDoor2().contains("used")){
                    setChoice(1);
                }else if(getDoor1().contains("used")){
                    setChoice(2);
                }
                System.out.println("you choose to switch to door "+getChoice());
            }
        }else if(x.contains("no"))
            System.out.println("You choose to stay with door "+getChoice());
        }
    }

    public void revealPlayerDoor(){
        switch(getChoice()){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Monty reveals your door contains "+getDoor1());
            break;
        case 2: 
            System.out.println("Monty reveals your door contains "+getDoor2());
            break;
        case 3:
            System.out.println("Monty reveals your door contains "+getDoor3());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your rand.nextInt(3) is zero-based, so it will return something in the range 0..2, not 1..3.

Comment: Your generatePrizeDoor() method should be setting all three doors in all three cases, but case 2 does setDoor1 twice, and case 3 does setDoor1 three times.

Comment: if the person has picked the right door, Monty should pick one of the other 2 doors at random, not deterministically.